# "XamlParseException was unhandled"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i am getting this exception every time i run the application. i dun know what it

> XamlParseException was unhandled.
>
> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'chrm.MainWindow' that matches the specified
>       binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

My code

GoogleChrome.cs

```
namespace chrm
{
class GoogleChrome
{
    public List<URL> URLs = new List<URL>();
    public IEnumerable<URL> GetHistory()
    {
        // Get Current Users App Data
        string documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath
        (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string[] tempstr = documentsFolder.Split('\\');
        string tempstr1 = "";
        documentsFolder += "\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default";
        if (tempstr[tempstr.Length - 1] != "Local")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tempstr.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                tempstr1 += tempstr[i] + "\\";
            }
            documentsFolder = tempstr1 + "Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default";
        }


        // Check if directory exists
        if (Directory.Exists(documentsFolder))
        {
            return ExtractUserHistory(documentsFolder);

        }
        return null;
    }


    IEnumerable<URL> ExtractUserHistory(string folder)
    {
        // Get User history info
        DataTable historyDT = ExtractFromTable("urls", folder);

        // Get visit Time/Data info
        DataTable visitsDT = ExtractFromTable("visits",
        folder);

        // Loop each history entry
        foreach (DataRow row in historyDT.Rows)
        {

            // Obtain URL and Title strings
            string url = row["url"].ToString();
            string title = row["title"].ToString();

            // Create new Entry
            URL u = new URL(url.Replace('\'', ' '),
            title.Replace('\'', ' '),
            "Google Chrome");

            // Add entry to list
            URLs.Add(u);
        }
        // Clear URL History
        DeleteFromTable("urls", folder);
        DeleteFromTable("visits", folder);

        return URLs;
    }

    void DeleteFromTable(string table, string folder)
    {
        SQLiteConnection sql_con;
        SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;

        // FireFox database file
        string dbPath = folder + "\\History";

        // If file exists
        if (File.Exists(dbPath))
        {
            // Data connection
            sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath +
            ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

            // Open the Conn
            sql_con.Open();

            // Delete Query
            string CommandText = "delete from " + table;

            // Create command
            sql_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, sql_con);

            sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Clean up
            sql_con.Close();
        }
    }

     DataTable ExtractFromTable(string table, string folder)
    {
        SQLiteConnection sql_con;
        SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
        SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        // FireFox database file
        string dbPath = folder + "\\History";

        // If file exists
        if (File.Exists(dbPath))
        {
            // Data connection
            sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath +
            ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

            // Open the Connection
            sql_con.Open();
            sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();

            // Select Query
            string CommandText = "select * from " + table;

            // Populate Data Table
            DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
            DB.Fill(DT);

            // Clean up
            sql_con.Close();
        }
        return DT;
    }
}
}
```

URL.cs

```
namespace chrm
{
class URL
{
    string url;
    string title;
    string browser;
    public URL(string url, string title, string browser)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    public string getData()
    {
        return browser + " - " + title + " - " + url;
    }
}
}
```

and finally Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace chrm
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    GoogleChrome ch = new GoogleChrome();
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        ch.GetHistory();
    }
 }
}
```

when i put debug in cs file .. i see its not going in DataTable ExtractFromTable(string table, string folder). So i am getting the error in mainwindow only .

what to do now?

ok .. when i catch the exception it gives me

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.\r\n   at chrm.GoogleChrome.ExtractFromTable(String table, String folder)\r\n   at chrm.GoogleChrome.ExtractUserHistory(String folder) in D:\html5\chrm\chrm\GoogleChrome.cs:line 45\r\n   at chrm.GoogleChrome.GetHistory() in D:\html5\chrm\chrm\GoogleChrome.cs:line 35\r\n   at chrm.MainWindow..ctor() in D:\html5\chrm\chrm\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 33

is it because dll i am using is v2.0 .. my app requires 4.0?

Comment: Seems your MainWindow Xaml is incorrect. Debug your code to see if the code flow go inside ch.GetHistory()? If it is really Xaml problem then you get the exception at InitializeComponent().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your `IOException`, I would indeed say it's an error due to the fact you are compiling in .NET 4.0 while trying to use a DLL built against .NET 2.0

Try adding this in the configuration section of your app.config file. You may try in your main application or in the DLL where you are using the piece of code above if need be:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```